# ZipArchive | Как добавлять в архив загружаемые файлы

Tags: php, ziparchive

Хотел бы спросить имеется ли возможность сразу во время загрузки файлов на сервер добавлять их в архив с помощью `ZipArchive` и сохранить в конечном итоге только архив? Я представляю такую цепочку:

- Загрузить через цикл все файлы
- Добавить файлы в архив
- Удалить файлы

Можно ли сократить эту цепочку до:

- Загрузить сразу файлы в архив и сохранить его

Comment: есть возможность сжать на клиенте, и и по сети отправить меньше

Comment: Основания идея использования архива это, чтобы вместо нескольких файлов для клиента был 1

Comment: а что мешает просто выполнить шелл скрипт который все запакует?

Answer (score 0):

Это пример бессмысленного вопроса.

Как сказал один умный человек, "преждевременная оптимизация - корень всех зол". Здесь мы видим постановку задачи на абсолютно пустом месте. Нет ни малейшей причины оптимизировать процесс. Учитывая, что пункт 3 делать не нужно, у нас остается 2. При том что файлы загружать все равно надо. То есть, загрузка с последующим добавлением в архив - это минимально необходимое количество действий.

Такого рода вопросы очень вредны для программиста. Они не только отнимают время не решение бессмысленных задач, но так же - в случае, если они будут реализованы - усложнят программу без малейшего на то основания.

Решаемая задача должна всегда браться не с потолка, а должна решать конкретную и насущную проблему